# How to delete multiple users from a group

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk

Not sure why facebook refered me here but anyhow, let me ask the question. I have a group on facebook with over 4000 members. I want to delete old members that are not active on the group anymore. Is there a way to select multiple users for deletion?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about using Facebook, not about programming. (Even if Facebook send you here, this is the wrong place.)

Comment: Actually I thing is a very useful question. If you need to remove a facebook group you need first to remove all users manually, one after each other. So teh practical way to do that thing is using javasscript or other routines in any language.

Answer (score 0):

How to get a list of ID's of your facebook group to avoid removal of active users, it's used to reduce as well a group from 10.000 to 5000 members as well as removal of not active members or old members "You will risk removing some few viewers of the group" "remember to open all comments while you browse down the page":

You will need to have Notepad++ for this process:

```
After you save the HTML. Remove all information before of document: 
"div id=contentArea" to 
"div id=bottomContent"
to avoid using messenger ID's,
```

somehow script will run problems if you have ID's by blocked users.

As well as a different example of how to parse as well as text and code out of HTML. And a range of numbers if they are with 2 digits up to 30.

You can try this to purge the list of member_id= and with them along with numbers from 2 to up to 30 digits long. Making sure only numbers and whole "member_id=12456" or "member_id=12" is written to file. Later you can replace out the member_id= with blanking it out. Then copy the whole list to a duplicate scanner or remove duplicates. And have all unique ID's. And then use it in the Java code below.

"This is used to purge all Facebook user ID's by a group out of a single HTML file after you saved it scrolling down the group"

```
Find: (member_id=\d{2,30})|.
Replace: $1
```

You should use the "Regular Expression" and ". matches newline" on above code.

Second use the Extended Mode on this mode:

```
Find: member_id=
Replace: \n
```

That will make new lines and with an easy way to remove all Fx0 in all lines to manually remove all the extra characters that come in buggy Notepad++

Then you can easily as well then remove all duplicates. Connect all lines into one single space between. The option was to use this tool which aligns the whole text with one space between each ID: https://www.tracemyip.org/tools/remove-duplicate-words-in-text/

As well then again "use Normal option in Notepad++":

```
Find: "ONE SPACE"
Replace ','
```

Remember to add ' to beginning and end

Then you can copy the whole line into your java edit and then remove all members who are not active. If you though use a whole scrolled down HTML of a page. ['21','234','124234'] <-- remember right characters from beginning. Extra secure would be to add your ID's to the beginning.

You put your code into this line:

```
var excludedFbIds = ['1234','11223344']; // make sure each id is a string!
```

The facebook group removal java code is on the user that as well posted to this solution.

Answer (score -2):

```
var deleteAllGroupMembers = (function () {
    var deleteAllGroupMembers = {};
    // the facebook ids of the users that will not be removed.
    // IMPORTANT: bobby.leopold.5,LukeBryannNuttTx!
    var excludedFbIds = ['1234','11223344']; // make sure each id is a string!
    var usersToDeleteQueue = [];
    var scriptEnabled = false;
    var processing = false;

    deleteAllGroupMembers.start = function() {
        scriptEnabled = true;
        deleteAll();
    };
    deleteAllGroupMembers.stop = function() {
        scriptEnabled = false;
    };

    function deleteAll() {
        if (scriptEnabled) {
            queueMembersToDelete();
            processQueue();
        }
    }

    function queueMembersToDelete() {
        var adminActions = document.getElementsByClassName('adminActions');
        console.log(excludedFbIds);
        for(var i=0; i<adminActions.length; i++) {
            var gearWheelIconDiv = adminActions[i];
            var hyperlinksInAdminDialog = gearWheelIconDiv.getElementsByTagName('a');
            var fbMemberId = gearWheelIconDiv.parentNode.parentNode.id.replace('member_','');
            var fbMemberName = getTextFromElement(gearWheelIconDiv.parentNode.parentNode.getElementsByClassName('fcb')[0]);

            if (excludedFbIds.indexOf(fbMemberId) != -1) {
                console.log("SKIPPING "+fbMemberName+' ('+fbMemberId+')');
                continue;
            } else {
                usersToDeleteQueue.push({'memberId': fbMemberId, 'gearWheelIconDiv': gearWheelIconDiv});
            }
        }
    }

    function processQueue() {
        if (!scriptEnabled) {
            return;
        }
        if (usersToDeleteQueue.length > 0) {
            removeNext();

            setTimeout(function(){
                processQueue();
            },1000);
        } else {
            getMore();
        }
    }

    function removeNext() {
        if (!scriptEnabled) {
            return;
        }
        if (usersToDeleteQueue.length > 0) {
            var nextElement = usersToDeleteQueue.pop();
            removeMember(nextElement.memberId, nextElement.gearWheelIconDiv);
        }
    }

    function removeMember(memberId, gearWheelIconDiv) {
        if (processing) {
            return;
        }
        var gearWheelHref = gearWheelIconDiv.getElementsByTagName('a')[0];
        gearWheelHref.click();
        processing = true;
        setTimeout(function(){
            var popupRef = gearWheelHref.id;
            var popupDiv = getElementByAttribute('data-ownerid',popupRef);
            var popupLinks = popupDiv.getElementsByTagName('a');
            for(var j=0; j<popupLinks.length; j++) {
                if (popupLinks[j].getAttribute('href').indexOf('remove.php') !== -1) {
                    // this is the remove link
                    popupLinks[j].click();
                    setTimeout(function(){
                        var confirmButton = document.getElementsByClassName('layerConfirm uiOverlayButton selected')[0];
                        var errorDialog = getElementByAttribute('data-reactid','.4.0');
                        if (confirmButton != null) {
                            if (canClick(confirmButton)) {
                                confirmButton.click();
                            } else {
                                console.log('This should not happen memberid: '+memberId);
                                5/0;
                                console.log(gearWheelIconDiv);
                            }
                        }
                        if (errorDialog != null) {
                            console.log("Error while removing member "+memberId);
                            errorDialog.getElementsByClassName('selected  layerCancel autofocus')[0].click();
                        } 
                        processing = false;
                    },700);
                    continue;
                }
            }
        },500);
    }

    function canClick(el) {
        return (typeof el != 'undefined') && (typeof el.click != 'undefined');
    }

    function getMore() {
        processing = true;
        more = document.getElementsByClassName("pam uiBoxLightblue  uiMorePagerPrimary");
        if (typeof more != 'undefined' && canClick(more[0])) {
            more[0].click();
            setTimeout(function(){
                deleteAll();
                processing = false;
           }, 2000);
        } else {
            deleteAllGroupMembers.stop();
        }
    }

    function getTextFromElement(element) {
        var text = element.textContent;
        return text;
    }

    function getElementByAttribute(attr, value, root) {
        root = root || document.body;
        if(root.hasAttribute(attr) && root.getAttribute(attr) == value) {
            return root;
        }
        var children = root.children,
            element;
        for(var i = children.length; i--; ) {
            element = getElementByAttribute(attr, value, children[i]);
            if(element) {
                return element;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
    return deleteAllGroupMembers;
})();
deleteAllGroupMembers.start();

// stop the script by entering this in the console: deleteAllGroupMembers.stop();
```

Use this in Chrome or Firefox Javascript control panel.

Comment: A bit more explanation would not go amiss.

Comment: This script does not answer the OP. The question was not how to delete all members, which this script will do, but how to delete _particular_ members matching an activity criterion.